# Simple content managment

Tags: looking-for-a-script, content, rss, management

I need to setup a content management system for a school to manage news items and bulletins. These bulletins would have to be placed into a number of different categories (Sport, Academic, etc.).

The backend of it would have to be used by some not very technically capable teachers. A front end is not required, only an RSS feed to be fed into existing applications.

I was thinking about using Wordpress, is there anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/), users I have dealt with love the admin interface, they just get it.

Answer (score 0):

This would sound bias but it might be a good idea to give a try of using Joomla. When it comes to friendliness Joomla and Wordpress are not far from each other. The good thing about Joomla is it is easy to expand for future features the school may think to add. At least for me it is very easy to create a custom theme in Joomla.